# Nginx redirect a specific file path to file path with an extra query param if it's not there

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

My redirection requirements are:

1. http://localhost/module/client/core/client_loader.js should redirect to http://localhost/module/client/core/client_loader.js?v=1.0
2. http://localhost/module/client/core/client_loader.js?s1=t1&s2=t2 should redirect to http://localhost/module/client/core/client_loader.js?s1=t1&s2=t2&v=1.0
3. http://localhost/module/client/core/client_loader.js?v=1.0 should not redirect
4. http://localhost/module/client/core/client_loader.js?s1=t1&v=1.0 should not redirect

If the filepath does not have a query paramerter "v" then it should append query parameter and redirect otherwise just leave it. Here conditions A{} and AB{} working but redirection is not working. nginx version is nginx/1.21.3. Any help please.

```
location  = /module/client/core/client_loader.js {
            set $cond "";
            if ($arg_v = "") {
               set $cond  A;
            }
            if ($is_args) {
                set $cond "${cond}B";
            }
            if ($cond = AB) {
                # if the path has query parameters but does not have "v" query param
                rewrite ^ /client_loader.js?$args&v={{ .Values.version }} break;
            }
            if ($cond = A) {
                # if the path doesn't have query parameters also does not have "v" query param
                rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?v={{ .Values.version }} break;
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need a redirect rather than internal URI rewrite. To get a redirect you need to use either `permanent` (for HTTP 301 redirection) or `redirect` (for HTTP 302 redirection) flag. nginx `rewrite` directive (as well as `location` one) works with so-called *normalized* URI which does not include a query part (check the `location` directive [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for additional details about URI normalization). And as it stated by the `rewrite` directive [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite):

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended, for example:
>
> ```
> rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /show?user=$1? last;
> ```

So you can add the following `if` block to your configuration:

```
if ($arg_v = '') {
    # add 'v' query argument if an URI is '/module/client/core/client_loader.js' and don't touch any other URI
    rewrite ^/module/client/core/client_loader\.js$ /module/client/core/client_loader.js?v={{ .Values.version }} permanent;
    # any other query arguments will be preserved
}
```

Comment: My services running within kubernates and exposed via ingress, the above change redirects but it includes pod internal kubernates url : http://client.svc.cluster.local:8001/module/client/core/client_loader.js?v=1.0

Comment: Unortunately I don't have a kubertetes knowledge and don't understand what does "pod internal kubernates url" really means, but if using a `location = /module/client/core/client_loader.js { ... }` ok to you, you can try `if ($arg_v = '') { rewrite ^ /module/client/core/client_loader.js?v={{ .Values.version }} permanent; }` inside that location.

Comment: any way, thanks for the help